# Azure Function Environment Variables

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to create a super basic Azure Function, but am having trouble with environment variables.  Following various tutorials online,

```
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
             .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
             .AddEnvironmentVariables()
             .Build();

        log.Info(config["AzureWebJobsStorage"]);
```

My local.settings.json looks like this:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "<language worker>",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "abc123",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "abc123",
    "MyBindingConnection": "abc123"
  },
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7071,
    "CORS": "*"
  }
}
```

When I run this locally, that

```
log.Info(config["AzureWebJobsStorage"]);
```

line returns nothing... but when I deploy to Azure I see "abc123" in the console.

If, however, I alter that line to

```
log.Info(config["Values:AzureWebJobsStorage"]);
```

Then when I run locally, I see "abc123" but when I deploy to Azure I see nothing.

Is there something I'm missing to be able to reach the environment variables the same way locally vs deployed?

EDIT: To clarify, these settings **are** configured in the app settings for the function: 
[image]

Comment: If my answer was useful and correct, please mark it as the accepted answer. This helps others who visit this page find the best answer as well as provides some positive feedback to me. Thank you.

Comment: I went to lunch after I posted this for an hour.  This answer was not helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you are using targeting the ~2 runtime for your Azure Functions you can access your configuration values through:

```
log.Info(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process));
```

Comment: Hi @Kane... thanks!  I tried this and get the same behavior locally.  Actually when I try locally this way, even when I try to reference "Variables:AzureWebJobsStorage" it returns nothing.  I'm going to try to re-install Azure Functions Core Tools and see what happens.

Comment: My function was actually running ~1 runtime... according to the tutorials I was reading it should have worked, but upgrading seemed like an easy enough thing to do and it worked.  Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

Those environmental variables work when you are testing your function locally. However, when you deploy to the Azure Function Portal, you need to setup your variables using their built-in system to handle Environmental Variables.

Copy and past your key-values into the sections that I highlighted in the image below.

<[image: Azure Functions Portal - Environmental]

Comment: Hi @MBak  That's exactly what I did, sorry.  Check the last part of my post.  I get a value returned if I call config["AzureWebJobsStorage"] on Azure.